In "Chosen One Protective Service", does everyone get the diagetic interface into rune magic that Rusty does?
In Andrew Seiple's Who Chooses the Chosen, first book of his Chosen One Protection Services, Rusty experiences his rune powers as a text interface of symbols that he sees in his mind's eye with exact numbers given for his chakra reserves, and the cost of a given spell. In the book, his mentors make reference to there being fixed reserves and the need to be aware of when a spell will exceed those reserves (because then the magic pulls from your body, causing potentially crippling injuries), but I don't remember anyone referring to having specific numbers. Is Rusty's interface unique to him, possibly as a result of his first rune being one of Memory?

For what it is worth, I'm directing queries to the author to see if I can get an answer.
